# checkout page choose a delivery address

Tags: php

I have a checkout page where user's address are listed. Its in this format:

```
<form action="confirm.php" method="post" name="checkout">
    <?php do { ?>
      <div class="panel panel-default" style="padding:0">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse<?php echo $row_Address['ID'] ?>">
              <?php echo $row_Address['FirstName'] ?>  <?php echo $row_Address['LastName'] ?>,  <?php echo $row_Address['City'] ?>  <?php echo $row_Address['Pincode'] ?></a>
            </h4>
          </div>
        <div id="collapse<?php echo $row_Address['ID'] ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">

            <p>

              <?php echo $row_Address['FirstName']; ?> <?php echo $row_Address['LastName']; ?><br><?php echo $row_Address['Address1']; ?><br><?php echo $row_Address['Address2']; ?><br><?php echo $row_Address['City']; ?><br><?php echo $row_Address['State']; ?><br><?php echo $row_Address['Country']; ?><br><?php echo $row_Address['Pincode']; ?>
              <br>

              <strong>Email:</strong> <?php echo $row_Address['Pincode']; ?><br>
              <strong> Phone:</strong> <?php echo $row_Address['Phone']; ?>
    <br>
<br>
     <button id="<?php echo $row_Address['ID']; ?>" type="submit" class="btn custombutton button--isi btn-primary">deliver to this address</button>
</p>            
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <?php } while ($row_Address = mysql_fetch_assoc($Address)); ?>
    <!-- repeat address -->
    </form>
```

So from the above codes, addresses are repeated are per user.

i have a button which id is `$row_Address['ID']` as all ID's are unique.

On click on any button i want to take that ID to next page ie confirm.php

then use that ID by $_GET['ID'] in confirm .php

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach is pass the `$row_Address['ID']` as a hidden value

```
<input type="hidden" name="customid" value="<?php echo $row_Address['ID']; ?> />
```

retrieve that on `confirm .php` by following code

```
$rowAddress = $_POST['customid'];
```

Comment: i did the same. yet not working. page goes to just confirm.php

Comment: what is the value you are getting on `confirm.php`?

Comment: i guess i had to move form within the repeat region. doing that & adding following helped
      `   <form action="confirm.php?ID=<?php echo $row_Address['ID'];?>" method="post" name="chk">`

Comment: but hidden element didn't help! 
         ` <form action="new-confirm.php?ID=<?php echo $row_Address['ID'];?>" method="post" name="chk">
<input name="Deliver" type="submit">

 </form> `

Comment: this is quite dangerous as compare to hidden value. Because one can easily change the value which is passing in url.

Comment: what would be the best way then?

Comment: `hidden` value is the best way. What exactly is the issue you are facing with `hidden` value?

Comment: one more way much safer use `session` but it will increase you efforts because you need to check session for previous value exist or not